# Least square estimation and nonlinear model

Tags: estimation, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

Suppoese X is the attribute and Y is the response as random variables. We observe (X,Y) jointly as a bi-variate normal variable, then least square estimation of Y as a regression function `E(Y|X)` is a linear function $\omega_0 + \omega_1X$.
Now, when we take joint distribution of (X,Y) other than normal distribution (such as uniform), then corresponding least square estimate as a regression function $E(Y|X)$ may not be a linear function.

I have the folllowing questions:

1. How can perform linear approximation of the regression function $E(Y|X)$ when (X,Y) is having non-normal joint distribution?
2. What would be estimation error of the corresponding linear approximation?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381072/how-to-test-whether-the-association-between-two-continuous-variables-varies-by-a/381082#381082, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123453/copulas-with-regression  and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308775/conditional-expectation-of-two-identical-marginal-normal-random-variables/308831#308831

Comment: I am looking for explicit examples such as if some how we came to know that the joint distribution of (X,Y) is unform, then the corresponding regression function is a piece-wise linear (i.e. a non-linear) function.